# Need data structure for elements with sets of tags, and can efficiently find all elements whose tags are a subset of an input set

Tags: algorithm, lua

I have some elements in a set A that have a set of tags from a set B. Is there a data structure that supports these operations?

1. Construction, given a set of all possible tags and all elements. (I will know all tags and elements before I do any lookups)
2. Given a set of tags, efficiently find all elements whose tags are a subset of the input set.

I am doing this in Lua, so I have access to mutable tables with constant(enough)-time insertion and deletion, and linear-time traversal.

The naive approach is to keep a list of all elements and go through every element and see if its tags are a subset of the input. This has time complexity O(nw), where n is the number of elements and w is the maximum number of tags that an element has. w will probably never exceed 10, so this time complexity could be considered linear.

Is there a data structure that will give me this kind of lookup, in sublinear time?

The context of this is for a simple chemical reaction system: A chemical reaction lists the reactants, and whenever a chemical container changes its contents, I need to find all the applicable reactions, which are the ones whose reactants are all in the container. This problem generalizes to anything where you need to do something when a set of things are fulfilled.

Comment: Only 10 tags?  Split A into 2^10=1024 subsets of A (for every subset of B).

Comment: I'm sorry for being ambiguous. By maximum number of tags that an element has, I meant that the set of tags associated with an element will never be larger than 10. But B itself will probably be 100 or so tags.

Comment: Well, there's always the trivial lookup table possibility. ​ (Store the output-sets in locations corresponding to the input-sets.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I would have to store them in locations corresponding to every superset of the inputs, or else check the location of every subset of an input set. The second would be more feasible and has been mentioned in the accepted answer. I might end up going that way if the number of possible reactions is large enough and the average tag count is low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-linear is not possible in the worst case because if the given set of tags contains ALL tags, then ALL elements must be returned. But here's an algorithm that can be sub-linear in the average case.

For each element, use a 128-bit integer (2 x 64-bit integers if you have to) to represent the 100 or so possible tags (i.e. each bit represents a different tag: 1 if the element has the tag, and 0 otherwise.)

Then sort the array based on the 128-bit integer representation.

Given a list of tags, turn it into the 128-bit integer representation so that you can use bit-wise operations to determine whether an element has a subset of the given tags or not. (Use OR operation, followed by a count of the number of 1s in the result.)

The actual speed up (other than the speed up by using bitwise operations) is explained below. For this, let us simplify the input down to 8 bits.

Suppose the list of tags were given as `01001100`.

Then you can search for `00000100` in the list of elements in `O(logn)` time because the list is sorted, and grab a list of elements until `00000101` is reached. Then you can jump to `00001000`, again in `O(logn)` time, and search there until you reach `00001101`, then jump to `01000000`, and so on.

The end result is that you've jumped over a significant number of elements, at the cost of spending `O(tlogn)` for the jumps, where `t` is the number of tags in the input set of tags.

You can take this idea a bit further by jumping more. i.e. jump to `00000100`, then jump to `00001000`, then to `00001100`, then to `01000000`, then to `01000100`, and so on. This results in spending `O(2^tlogn)` time for jumping around, but this maybe worth it if `t << n` and `2^t` is manageable.

Comment: If you jump to `00001000`, and search there until you reach `00001101`, you will go through a lot of elements which do not satisfy search criteria.  Actually, that makes your search almost linear, the estimation `O(t logn)` is incorrect.

Comment: But your second algorithm with `O(2^t logn)` time complexity is pretty valid.

Comment: I think he just meant the jumps take O(t logn) time, but didn't specify how much time is saved.

Comment: I am unable to specify how much time is saved because that would depend on the list of elements and the input tags. In the worst case, my algorithm still performs in `O(n)` time bound, which I already specified at the start. Even `O(2^t logn)` is NOT valid by itself, because there could be many elements with the same set of tags. @Reimu has it correct, that these time bounds were just for the jumps.

Comment: O(2^t logn) would be correct in my case, for the originally-unspecified reason that my elements would have unique tag-sets. I don't think I will use that version though, since it is likely that I have less elements than tags. Another constraint I forgot to specify is that no element will have a tag-set that is the subset of another element's tag-set.